# CSV reader creating problem with special character (“),("),('),(/) while reading the CSV file by java code?

Tags: java

Sample Data:

```
"Here Comes Santa Claus (from “pitch Perfect 2" Soundtrack)","PITCH PERFECT 2",NULL,"Here Comes ameda Claus (from “amen Perfect 2" Amen)",NULL,"HERE COMES SANTA CLAUS (FROM “PITCH PERFECT 2" SOUNDTRACK)",NULL,"PITCH IMPACT 2","00-00-0000 00:00:00".
```

Use this pom.xml dependency to read file :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Using the below java code :

```
RFC4180Parser rfc4180Parser = new RFC4180ParserBuilder().build();
CSVReaderBuilder csvReaderBuilder = new CSVReaderBuilder(filereader)
                    .withCSVParser(rfc4180Parser);
csvReader = csvReaderBuilder.build();
String[] nextRecord;
int i=0;
            while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Data " + nextRecord [i]);
    System.out.println("New Records");

}
```

**My output :-**

```
Here Comes Santa Claus (from “pitch Perfect 2" Soundtrack)","PITCH PERFECT 2",NULL,"Here Comes ameda Claus (from “amen Perfect 2" Amen)",NULL,"HERE COMES SANTA CLAUS (FROM “PITCH PERFECT 2" SOUNDTRACK)
New Records
NULL
New Records
PITCH IMPACT 2
New Records
00-00-0000 00:00:00
New Records
```

**Output should be like this  :--**

```
Comes Comes Santa Amen(from “Amen Amen2" Amen)
New Records
Amen2Amen22
New Records
NULL
New Records
Amen2 ameda Claus (from “amen Amen2 2" Amen)
New Records
NULL
New Records
HERE COMES SANTA CLAUS (FROM “PITCH PERFECT 2" SOUNDTRACK)
New Records
NULL
New Records
PITCH IMPACT 2
New Records
00-00-0000 00:00:00
New Records
```

Comment: Your sample data isn't valid CSV. Try to fix that.

Comment: What needs to correct in that? Just simplify it

Answer (score 1):

As @Janoz says, your CSV isn't valid, because you have quotes (`"`) inside the values that need to be escaped.

Since you are using a [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) parser you need to escape them by duplicating the quotes:

```
"Here Comes Santa Claus (from “pitch Perfect 2"" Soundtrack)","PITCH PERFECT 2",NULL,"Here Comes ameda Claus (from “amen Perfect 2"" Amen)",NULL,"HERE COMES SANTA CLAUS (FROM “PITCH PERFECT 2"" SOUNDTRACK)",NULL,"PITCH IMPACT 2","00-00-0000 00:00:00".
```

Comment: This we can do but can't we do with some code because in DB it is coming like this only and we need to  migrate this DB value by java.So need solution with this only. And like this in csv file like this minumum 1 lakh DB entries are like this only.

Comment: @Rajan I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. If the CSV is coming from a DB, then you need to fix that.

Comment: Ok thanks @RoToRa. I got the point i need to correct in DB records  only. I thought without doing any correction from DB records will do  something by java code itself.

Comment: @Rajan: Just to extend: The DB records are probably OK. The export of the records to CSV is broken.

Comment: it is not like that because everytime i took in some columns only this kind of special character is there. So i think DB records only needs to modify it.